# How to ignore some objects when filter an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

I have an array `returnedDocs` in code below (shortened via `let returnedDocs = result.application.modules.module.moduleItem;`) that I got as response from API, it structure is pretty complex. Some nested objects are arrays some values are placed few levels deep in the structure.

I use filter method to get only those elements that got specific value.

```
          let toFilterSix = returnedDocs.filter(
            o =>
              o.repeatableGroup.repeatableGroupItem.vocabularyReference
                .vocabularyReferenceItem.formattedValue._text === "Abdomen"
          );
          this.filterArray6 = toFilterSix;
```

Normally it works fine but in below example one of `repeatableGroupItem` is an array with two elements (image).

[image: arrayInArray]

I've got an error due to fact that there is unexpected array within filtered objects:

```
Results.vue?82a0:202 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'vocabularyReferenceItem' of undefined
    at eval (Results.vue?82a0:202)
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at eval (Results.vue?82a0:201)
```

How can I avoid the error when do filter on other, non-array elements?

Here you can examine the data model, it's console.log'ed: https://lucid-villani-539a6f.netlify.com/results

Comment: please provide an example of your data model, and if possible try to rephrase and simplify your question a bit - as it stands it's a little difficult to interpreted.

Comment: You probably want to look at [Test for existence of nested JavaScript object key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2631001/215552) to test for the existence of the property you're targeting before descending to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to ignore the arrays, you can simply test whether `repeatableGroup` has a `vocabularyReferences` property.

```
let toFilterSix = returnedDocs.filter(
  o =>
  o.repeatableGroup.repeatableGroupItem.vocabularyReference &&
  o.repeatableGroup.repeatableGroupItem.vocabularyReference.vocabularyReferenceItem.formattedValue._text === "Abdomen"
);
```

If you want to search the array as well, you can use an `if` statement to search that when it's an array.

```
let toFilterSix = returnedDocs.filter(
  o => {
    if (Array.isArray(o.repeatableGroup.repeatableGroupItem)) {
      return o.repeatableGroup.repeatableGroupItem.some(el => el.vocabularyReference.vocabularyReferenceItem.formattedValue._text === "Abdomen");
    } else {
      return o.repeatableGroup.repeatableGroupItem.vocabularyReference.vocabularyReferenceItem.formattedValue._text === "Abdomen";
    }
  });
```

Comment: Great thanks! It saves the day (I used second snippet) and I have a starting point for some of my other bottlenecks with filtering and exceptions for non existing elements returned from API.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to look for `"Abdomen"` regardless of whether it's a single object *or* an array of those objects, you could use `[].concat(repeatableGroupItem)`. This allows you to safely assume you're dealing with an array instead of handling each case individually.

From there you could use `.some()` to determine if `"Abdomen"` exists within any of the items.

```js
// This array contains 4 objects... 
//   1: repeatableGroupItem as single object, containing "Abdomen"
//   2: repeatableGroupItem as array of objects, containing "Abdomen"
//   3: repeatableGroupItem as single object, without "Abdomen"
//   4: repeatableGroupItem as array of objects, without "Abdomen"
const returnedDocs = [{ repeatableGroup: { repeatableGroupItem: { vocabularyReference: { vocabularyReferenceItem: { formattedValue: { _text: "Abdomen" } } } } } }, { repeatableGroup: { repeatableGroupItem: [{ vocabularyReference: { vocabularyReferenceItem: { formattedValue: { _text: "Abdomen" } } } }, { vocabularyReference: { vocabularyReferenceItem: { formattedValue: { _text: "Abdomen" } } } } ] } }, { repeatableGroup: { repeatableGroupItem: { vocabularyReference: { vocabularyReferenceItem: { formattedValue: { _text: "Not Abdomen" } } } } } }, { repeatableGroup: { repeatableGroupItem: [{ vocabularyReference: { vocabularyReferenceItem: { formattedValue: { _text: "Not Abdomen" } } } }, { vocabularyReference: { vocabularyReferenceItem: { formattedValue: { _text: "Not Abdomen" } } } } ] } }];

const result = returnedDocs.filter(o => {
  const item = [].concat(o.repeatableGroup.repeatableGroupItem);
  return item.some(i => i.vocabularyReference.vocabularyReferenceItem.formattedValue._text === "Abdomen");
});

//Logs items 1 and 2
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you, great case to study and use. I have more of that `undefined` stuff within my filters :)

Comment: No problem! I wrote this [simple example](https://jsfiddle.net/eLnd8h7m/) to more clearly explain what the `.concat()` is doing.